# Paused & want to delete partially downloaded Yosemite

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

I was installing Yosemite Beta, however, I paused the download as I have not backup my Mac. Does anyone know how I can delete the paused download of it? It's driving me nuts! I can't just press "delete" like my other Apps!

Answer (score 33):

There are two simpler ways for this:

1. In Mac App Store Updates page, simply hold down <kbd>option</kbd>, and you'll see the **Pause** button changes to **Cancel**.
2. In Launchpad, hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and you'll see apps icons begin to wiggle (just like they would on iOS). Click the **X** that has appeared and the update will be canceled.

Comment: Yes, this step helped me in Yosemite. http://www.cultofmac.com/224342/cancel-instead-of-pausing-your-mac-app-store-updates-os-x-tips/

Comment: Did that, still no, comes back. Guess file permission issues.

Answer (score 26):

Best way to do this is to enable the Debug menu for the App Store. Do this:

1. Run this command from Terminal:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true && killall App\ Store
   ```
2. Go to the the App Store debug menu and reveal the download folder. You can delete the whole thing from Finder.

   [image]
3. Log out and back in to your Mac.
4. Empty the trash.

Comment: Best way to get rid of those insanely large development version that download behind your back. Or anything downloaded from the App Store that matter. Really helps if you have a tiny SSD

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Sierra

Answer (score 12):

In Launchpad, click and hold on the icon for the download, and an 'x' will appear in the upper left-hand corner, clicking the 'x' will delete the download.

Answer (score 7):

Partial downloads are stored in `/private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.appstore/`. Delete the partial download from there and reset the Mac App Store from the debug menu if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In App Store go to Purchases tab and hold down the option key and you will see the Pause button turns to Cancel, only click on cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close App Store
2. In the Finder search for: com.apple.appstore
3. delete the whole com.apple.appstore folder
4. empty trash
5. restart the App Store

Answer (score 0):

To delete an active download for Yosemite in the Trash can, I had to switch to Safe Mode (Hold down SHIFT Key while booting) before I could delete it.
HTH